# Use original image, not cached, in pinterest pin it button

Tags: product-images, social-buttons

Is there a way to use the original image path instead of the cached one for the pinterest pinit button for products with multiple images?

```
domain_name/media/catalog/product/p/l/image.png
```

instead of:

```
domain_name/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/p/l/image.png
```

Using this line of code

```
$_baseUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
$_baseUrl."catalog/product".$_product->getImage()
```

loads only the base image, regardless of the selected image

This is the code used in view.phtml for loading the pin it button:

```
<?php
  $_pinlink['url'] = $_product->getProductUrl();
  $_pinlink['media'] = $_baseUrl."catalog/product".$_product->getImage();
  $_pinlink['description'] = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') . " - " . strip_tags($_product->getDescription());?>
  <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?<?php echo http_build_query($_pinlink) ?>" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal"></a>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

Thank you,

Comment: "loads only the base image, regardless of the selected image" - What do you mean with "selected image" in contrast to "base image"? Which image do you want to get the URL for?